# Python, mkdir error when values have "N/A" in them

Tags: python

How can I alter my code so that N/A's or still write them regardless of the N/As.

Ie if I have a path like `:O/Stack/Over/Flow/Stack-2023-N/A-Test`  my code will not work. It is because of the `/` in `N/A`. How can I identify the N/A lines in my dataframe `pl_dest` column "Folder_Name_to_create" and still make the directorys?

Code:

```
for folder in pl_dest['Folder_Name_to_create']:
    try:
        pathlib.Path(folder).mkdir()
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

Comment: search for `"N/A"` and replace with `"NA"` or the value of your choice.

Comment: Don't store paths like that. If you do, you cannot disambiguate the N/A's you want to replace from something like `FileN/Archives/t.txt`